# Difference between $Context and Evaluate[Context[]] using DumpSave

Tags: contexts, dumpsave

If I were to type both individually with // FullForm, It would seem that both are the same:
However, in the context for example of a dumpsave:

```
DumpSave["~/Documents/test.mx", $Context]

DumpSave["~/Documents/test2.mx", Evaluate[Context[]]]
```

it would seem that the latter works as expected while the former does not.
Why is that?

Comment: I want to save all the symbols that have been defined in the current context. The latter does exactly that, while the former just does not do anything at all.

Comment: The difference is that `$Context` does not get evaluated because **`DumpSave` has the attribute `HoldRest`** (see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldRest.html) for details). `DumpSave["~/Documents/test.mx", Evaluate@$Context]` works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues. First of all `Context[]` is the same here and can be replaced with `$Context` to make the example clearer. Now:

1. `DumpSave` is `HoldRest` so in case of `symbol = 2` it can save that definition instead of seeing `2`.
2. `DumpSave["file", symbol]` will save defnitions of `symbol`. So will `DumpSave["file", $Context]`. It will save information that `$Context = whateverthecontextthereis`.

If you want to `` DumpSave["file", "Global`"] `` you need to explicitly write it or *inject* it before `DumpSave` is evaluated. Those are most common ways to do this:

```
Function[x, DumpSave["file", x]] @ $Context

DumpSave["file", #]& @ $Context

DumpSave["file", Evaluate @ $Context]

With[{ x = $Context }, DumpSave["file", x] ]
```

In your recent question you had `DumpSave["file", { Evaluate @ $Context }]`. It didn't work because `Evaluate` only works on the first level of an expression that has `Hold*` attribute. This expression here is `DumpSave` but on the first level it has a string and a list so evaluator does not care about `Evaluate`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer! I understand the mistake much better now.